# Trying to update a .mdb file, but changes are not appearing on intranet

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-access

Like the title suggests, I am attempting to update a Microsoft Access (.mdb) file. I can edit fields and values just fine, but whenever I try to upload it to an intranet page I'm working on, my changes do not appear!

This chunk of code controls how things are rendered on the intranet site. It is built into a dropdown menu.

```
openStr = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("../db/pagers/pagers.mdb")
Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open openStr
SQL = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE physician<>true AND lastName NOT LIKE '%??%' AND lastName NOT LIKE '%spare%' AND status='Active' ORDER BY lastName,firstName" 
Set record = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
record.Open sql, cn, 3, 2
```

Refreshing the application pool doesn't seem to do anything, either.

Any ideas?

Comment: do you see ldb file where you upload?

Comment: Sounds like you've not updated the proper MDB file.

Comment: @marathonman: There is no such extension in the folder that I upload to.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: The file name is correct.

Comment: Well, if you have really updated the right file, but the new data isn't showing up... ASP.NET isn't going to make up data.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: What is your suggestion for a fix?

Comment: Find the real database file. If you don't see a file named `pagers.ldb` in the same directory, you've probably edited the wrong file.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: The only issue I have with that is that I'm remotely connected. The remote machine doesn't have Access installed, either, so I have to work on my own machine, then transfer the files to the remote server.

Comment: Okay; either way, you need to be sure you've found the correct file.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your help, @Andrew Barber!